# How to determine why certain resources are showing up in the cloud resource manager?

Tags: security, google-cloud-platform

Recently when inspecting the cloud resource manager I've noticed some odd projects and apps listed there that I'm pretty certain that I didn't create.

[image]

I only have read-only access to them and not designated as the owner, so I can't get rid of them and they're just cluttering up my resource manager.

[image]

[image]

**How can I determine the reason for them showing up in my resource manager?**

Could this mean my account is/was compromised at some point? Or is this due to someone just sharing their projects/apps with my account?

If it's the former how could I potentially trace the point that was compromised? I have 2FA set up on my google account and checking the list of signed-in devices only lists devices that I have currently in my possession / direct control.

Comment: Please provide more details about "odd projects and apps". It'll be great if you're able to add some screenshots to your question as well.

Comment: @SerhiiRohoza Added some screenshots of the suspect apps/projects.

Comment: Do you use your personal email at gmail.com for access to Google Cloud? Have you tried any courses or trainings before that could explain some projects related to your email?

Comment: Yes, this is my personal account, in the screenshot provided I masked out the entries that I know for certain are my resources. The three heavily labelled entries seem to be implicitly pointing to some travel agency org in New Delhi which is definitely not something I've been in contact with and so seems suspicious.

Comment: Have you tried to contact with project owners that you're able to see? Strictly saying anyone who knows your email is able to grant some viewer permissions to you and as a result you'll be able to see their projects.

Answer (score 2):

These projects are showing up because you have been granted a role with at least project get permission on those projects. It could be either your google account was added directly, or your account is part of a group or domain that was added.

This doesn't necessarily point to your account being compromised and is expected behavior.